# Wordpress site receives requests multiple times from same IP

Tags: wordpress, resources, system

My site is receiving about 10 requests at once that increases CPU resources usage to 100%. i diagnosed through Terminal using `htop` or `ps -faux` commands it shows below process 10 or more times at once.

> /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php-cgi /home/myusername/public_html/wpsite.com/index.php

Then i verified who is requesting for so many times with below code adding in index.php file on my wordpress website's root directory.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$data = 'IP: '.$ip.' REF: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].PHP_EOL;
$fp = fopen('/home/myusername/public_html/wpsite.com/chk.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
```

Onward i visited all of my pages one by one *(home, category, single product, contact etc)* i found my IP and the Referral page as i navigated which seems fine, as one request for each. but after a while i'm able to see `8,10,15` requests at once from same IP.

```
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
IP: 157.47.79.209 REF: refweb .com
```

i'm not sure why it's happening. is it wordpress theme's fault or it's normal to make requests to `index.php` in such amount? Please advise what i can do to get it fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short yes, there are multiple things that lead to this:

- Bots trying automatically brute force the backend, which is normal since they automatically detect if your site is wordpress.
- Crawlers from search engines
- Referral spam
- ...

Since you have to realize that this all happens automatically it's always good to use a Firewall (at server or at application Level). They will ban traffic like that. Moreover good passwort security and so on should be always there.

Comment: i've installed wordfence and security shield plugins. Configured firewall setting for both. after that system resources seem fine but index.php file is still writing IP and Ref requests for more than 10 times at once in `chk.txt` file. i'm not sure firewall is working or not at this stage.

Comment: Yeah, Wordfence can only handle access after init, since it's a plugin. If your accounts are protected and your plugins up two date this is no issue. You could use Fail2Ban or something like that on the Server.